# TACL process to stop PID process

Tags: macros, tandem

I have been creating basic macros in TACL Tandem and I would like to know if there is any way to capture the PIDs of processes that keep a file open to apply a ''stop'' to it.

The file has several processes keeping it open and I would like to be able to stop them.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).